# Creating select list in full-hour increments

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Is there a way to generate something like the following markup:

```
<select> 
    <option value="0000">00:00AM</option>
    <option value="0100">01:00AM</option>
    <option value="0200">02:00AM</option>
    <option value="0300">03:00AM</option>
    <!--rest of options omitted for brevity-->
</select>
```

... all the way up to 11:00PM,

I'm using Angular.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Use Javascript?? And you don't have 23 in AM/PM

Comment: Yes. and sorry I edit my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In some controller you should pre-generate these values:

```
$scope.hours = {};

//first 12 hours
$scope.hours['0000'] = '12:00AM';
for(var i = 1; i < 12; ++i) {
    var hour = i < 10 ? '0' + i : i;
    $scope.hours[hour + '00'] = hour + ':00AM';
}

//last 12 hours
$scope.hours['1200'] = '12:00PM';
for(var i = 1; i < 12; ++i) {
    var hour = i < 10 ? '0' + i : i;
    $scope.hours[i + 12 + '00'] = hour + ':00PM';
}
```

And then in your template:

```
<select> 
    <option ng-repeat="(value, label) in hours | orderBy: value" value="{{ value }}">
        {{ label }}
    </option>
</select>
```

Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hspqfouq/1/

Answer (score 0):

you can use following script :

```
<select id="hours">

</select>
<script>
var data="";
for (var i=0;i<12;i++)
{

  d=i*1;
  d1="0";
  d2="00";
  if (i>9) {d1="";}
 data+="<option value='"+d1+d+d2+"'>"+d1+d+":"+d2+"AM</option>";
}
var s=document.getElementById("hours");
s.innerHTML=data;
</script>
```

you can see the live output in this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bcdxsdch/) link